# Why is there a little mark on the right after using display inline and anchor tag?

Tags: html, css, anchor, padding

I don't know if you noticed, but my anchor tags have a little mark on the right which are most likely caused by the css mixed with the html. Here it is :

```
<ul>

    <a href="#"> <li> <strong> Home Page </strong> </li> </a>
    <a href="#"> <li> <strong> My Profile </strong> </li> </a>
    <a href="#"> <li> <strong> Categories</strong> </li> </a>
    <a href="#"> <li> <strong> Contact </strong> </li> </a>

</ul>
```

Here is the css:

```
   li {
   display: inline-block;
   list-style-type: none;
   padding-left: 25px;
   }   

   nav {
   width: 970px;
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;
   }

   a {
   color: #C3C3C3;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   }
```

Now, if you try the code yourself you will have a small little line on the right, what is it caused by and how can i eliminate it?

Comment: that is caused due to the `text-decoration` of anchor tag

Comment: if you don't want to use any extra `css`, just remove the space between the  closing tags `li` and `a`, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p4dn4njb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css rule to your anchor tag:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

this will remove that underscore line at the end of the link.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should no use `a` tag inside `ul`. It's not W3C compliant.
Right way will be:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Home Page</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>My Profile</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Categories</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

You could check the validity of your markup at the http://validator.w3.org/

The marks are underscores of the spaces. It's no good practice to use spaces as separators. Using styles for margins and padding is better way.

Answer (score 0):

Copy following code:
First way
**CSS**

```
 a:-webkit-any-link
 {    
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Second Way
**CSS**

```
a {
   color: #C3C3C3;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-decoration:none;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This little line is a fragment of default underline-anchor-style. So just add `text-decoration: none` for tag `<a>`.